# What to do esp in Debugging

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, stack

so , I will  to Understand debugging , i am very new and I am not a IT student.. .I am since Three Days this exercise to Understand , but without sucess...

I working with Linux and the Program GDB:

```
1 #include <string.h>
2 #include <stdio.h>
3
4 void overflowed() {
5 printf("%s\n", "Execution Hijacked");
6 }
7
8 void function1(char *str){
9 char buffer[5];
10 strcpy(buffer, str); (**3**)
11 } (**2**)
12 void main(int argc, char *argv[])
13 {
14 function1(argv[1]); (**1**)
15 printf("%s\n", "Executed normally");
16 }
```

The Number 1 , 2 , 3 are the Program Break Punkt .

```
(gdb) break 14
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048433: file overflowtest.c, line 14.
(gdb) break 10
Breakpoint 2 at 0x804840e: file overflowtest.c, line 10.
(gdb) break 11
Breakpoint 3 at 0x8048420: file overflowtest.c, line 11.
```

Break the line 14,10 and 11 .

than with run to given Four A

```
(gdb) run AAAA
Starting program: /home/georgia/overflowtest AAAA

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0xbfb73004) at overflowtest.c:14
14      function(argv[1]);
```

than with **x/16xw $esp** to my  First Break ,line 14 , i come

```
 (gdb) x/16xw $esp
 0xbfb72f50: 0xb77e6ff4 0x08049ff4  0xbfb72f78  0x08048489
 0xbfb72f60: 0xb780a7b0 0xbfb72f80  0xbfb72fd8  0xb769e775
 0xbfb72f70: 0x08048470 0x08048340  0xbfb72fd8  0xb769e775
 0xbfb72f80: 0x00000002 0xbfb73004  0xbfb73010  0xb77fab40
```

so, i to search to Understand , what on the far left is **0xbfb72f50:** and all Hex back from it come, his meaning.... . Can Please anybody help me with easy Words explain , to describe it ? , Very Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , How i Understande the Memory Adress on the far left :

```
0xbfb72f50:
0xbfb72f60:
0xbfb72f70:
0xbfb72f80:
```

are the stack framen where start my Three [breakpoints](https://picload.org/image/dapcrcgi/breakpoint.png) ,but i don't know what the Fisrt Adress to do.... , sorry about this questions , but i am not a Student from IT ....i learn self to Home....

So , answer me self:

Far left are the [Memory Adress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address_register) and what First back to come are the [Content-addressable memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory) , 0xb77e6ff4 is the **ESP** of the main ’s stack frame  . **ESP** marks the lowest memory address of a Stack , **EBP** is the highest address , Here 0xbfb72f78 .

Answer (score 0):

The first column is the address, that is, on the first line, the value of the `%esp` register.

For an explanation of the stack pointer (`%esp`) and stack frame (`%ebp`) registers, consult a text on compiler construction, such as chapter 6, *Activation Records*, in Appel's *Modern compiler implementation in ML*. Relevant keywords are *activation records* and *stack frames*.  [Wikipedia has some basic information, too.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#STACK-FRAME)

Comment: But , from where come 0xbfb72f50 ?

Comment: It's the value of `%esp`, a processor register. see `print $esp`. (For technical reasons, the assembler uses `%` for register names, while GDB uses `$`.)

Comment: Hallo , my assenbler knowledge is very low ...as i Understande , when a Program to start ,start a Proces and with this Proces starting Four Status Data , one of then ,the Stacksegment .Every Stacksegment have a Adress , my Problem is , i can not identify the register %esp and %ebp  what to do , i have to reading %esp is low memory and %ebp high memory , but have not Undestand the Concept..

Comment: Well, you'll have to review a text on compiler construction for the basics.

Comment: yes , but i to search since a Week easy basic explanation about compiler and i having not found... all which i to see are for me very difficult....